# Generating a PE format executable

Tags: windows, assembly, portable-executable

I'm trying to generate a PE format executable; I'm at the stage where I have something that dumpbin is happy with, and as far as I can tell is not materially different from an empty program linked with Microsoft's linker, but Windows still rejects it: [PE file - what's missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585549/pe-file-whats-missing)

If I had some algorithm for generating a valid PE file, maybe I could hill climb from there. Here's what I've found so far:

- There's plenty of documentation, sample code and tools for *reading* PE files, as opposed to generating them from scratch.
- PE Bliss lists generation among its features, but won't compile.
- Sample assembly language templates for PE file generation concentrate on minimizing size. The most promising looking one generates a file that Windows rejects even though as far as I can see it should be accepted; the one I found that did work, ironically, generates a file that Windows accepts even though as far as I can see it should be rejected, since almost every nominally essential component is missing or malformed.

Is there any sample code available that generates a correct PE file?

Comment: *"There's plenty of documentation, sample code and tools for reading PE files, as opposed to generating them from scratch."* I don't think so. Compilers and linkers must know this to generate PE executables.

Comment: @m0skit0 So they must. On the other hand, they typically don't come with documentation on how they do it, so while as a fallback I could git-clone an MLOC-scale program and start deleting things until I have a minimal correct solution, I suppose I'm hoping for something just a little easier :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure GCC (or any open source project) must have some documentation about that ;)

Comment: I wrote a high-level x86 assembler a long time ago that also included a PE linker. The binary and the source code is available [here](http://jiggawatt.org/badc0de/nqa.htm). The interesting parts would be in src/nqa.ex (the functions for generating the import/export/relocation tables and all the headers). Although it's written in a somewhat obscure language, it should still be understandable for someone who knows C/C++/Java.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the classic page about generating PE from scratch:

http://www.phreedom.org/research/tinype

As for the generic list of required/optional parts, see corkami page on the PE format:

http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE

See also the code tree for many examples of small PE files, generated completely from scratch.